# Disable test ads while publishing app in Windows Phone store. How test ads work?

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob

I have few question regarding test ads in windows phone application.

In Windows Phone 8, we have to mention `ForceTesting = true` to enable test ads. As I've mentioned code below. 
Please take a look

```
 AdView bannerAd = new AdView            
           {
                Format = AdFormats.Banner,
                AdUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxx/yyyyyyy"
            };
            bannerAd.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
            bannerAd.FailedToReceiveAd += OnFailedToReceiveAd;            
            gridad.Children.Add(bannerAd);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
            adRequest.ForceTesting = true;            // It leads to execute demo ads. NO REAL ads
            bannerAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
```

It works fine in emulator.

but what about in real devices ? what would happen if user download it from store after publishing app. Will they keep getting same test ads instead of real ads ?

In android there is option to include test device id to uniquely identify device, but in Windows Phone there is no such option. How google distinguish emulator, test device or normal devices(user who download app from store) ?

In short,  what should I need to opt  code between "ForceTesting = true" and  with "ForceTesting = false"  for publish app on store.
Please guide me. :)

Comment: When submitting the app you need to remove ForceTesting = true parameter. As it is only for testing the sdk weather the sdk  is working fine with the app or not.

Answer (score 0):

When i tried to mingle with `admob`, i went through this where i didn't had to use `ForceTesting`.

[AdMob Windows Phone 8](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/wp/quick-start)

But still from [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/wp/banner) page where i noticed under the `Test Ads`, it says `ForceTesting` is just only for development purposes.

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
adRequest.ForceTesting = false;
```

before uploading your solution app to the Store.

You ask:

> How google distinguish emulator, test device or normal devices(user
>   who download app from store) ?

Google does not make the difference between real devices and emulators, that is why they ask to use the Test Ads. However, for the ads, Google Adsense has an algorithm to pin-point any strange activity regarding false impressions or clicks on the advertisement.